# Setup daily disk quota

Tags: quota

I already setup disk quota using the `quota` package, but what I want is the quota to be reset everyday. Say I use 10 GB on Monday and the limit is 10 GB, on Tuesday I will be able to write 10 GB more, etc...

I want to do this to prevent SSD wearing, because I know I store many temporary useless files that takes up a lot of space.

If it's not possible to do so with the `quota` package, then what alternative should I consider? I mainly choose the `quota` package because it integrates well with KDE.